# Primefaces galleria - how to navigate without filmStrip

Tags: primefaces

I need to have primefaces galleria without the film strip at the bottom. When I used showFilmstrip="false", there is no way to navigate manually. Even adding autoPlay="true" does not make the contents to move.

```
<p:galleria id="gal" value="#{articleController.welcomes}" var="w" autoPlay="true" showFilmstrip="false" >
    <h:outputLabel value="#{w.sinhalaTopic}" ></h:outputLabel>
</p:galleria>
```

Is there any way to have a gallaria without film strip at the bottom, yet enable to navigate with the arrows on either sides? If that is not possible, is there any other similar primefaces component to be used instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.ui-galleria-filmstrip-wrapper {
    display:none;
}
```

Add upper code into your `.css` file, this will make the strip hidden at the bottom of `p:galleria`.